# How to Append pictures in Matlab?

Tags: image, matlab

I want to do this pseudocode in a system without imagemagick but I have Matlab 2016a and Java in the system

```
convert 1.png 2.png +append result.png
```

Assume you want to concatenate in a loop like the following such that dimensions may not match. 
However, all objects 1,2,...,N have exactly the same dimensions. 
The following loop, however, concatenates two pictures at the same time, making the dimensions different with subsequent images: bigImage vs new image.

```
iterationCounter=1;

result=0;
while(iterationCounter < 3)
    imgRGB=imread(filenamePng); % Images 1,2, ..., N have same dimensions.

    if (result==0)
        result=imgRGB;
    end

    % http://stackoverflow.com/a/35915990/54964
    if (ismatrix(result(:,:,1)))
        heightRatio=size(result,1)/size(imgRGB,1);
        wantedSize=int16([size(result,1), size(imgRGB,2)*heightRatio]);
        imgResized=imresize(imgRGB, wantedSize);
        result=[result, imgResized];
    end

    iterationCounter=iterationCounter+1;

end
```

where output is an empty picture.

---

How can you do the horizontal appending of the images in Matlab/Java?

Comment: If you can change the resolution and colourspace of images to be compatible, then you can use simple `BothImages=[Image1,Image2];` command.

Comment: @Crowley Actually, I have done individually `parula` colormap messes up the decoration. So I am now storing raw gray-pictures instead such that I could apply the colormap to one big picture at once.

Comment: I meant thas some images are represented by `m x n` matrix with `colormap` doing the colours and other are represented by `m x n x 3` matix while 3rd dimension desribes the colour in, say RGB, colourspace. Dimensions must fit so concatenation won't throw an error.

Comment: Yes, no problem with that. I am mostly in interested in fitting the colorspaces correctly. I think grayscale is the only way to do it bijectively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
imwrite([imread('1.png') imread('2.png')], '12.png');
```

*Note: They should have the same width/height depending on how you are appending them.*

Answer (score 1):

in general, when you concat two images horizontally, and they both have the same number of rows, the following code does the trick:

```
I1 = imread('coins.png');
I2 = imread('coins.png');
appendedIm = [I1,I2];
```

however, if you need to change I2 dimensions to fit to I1 height, you can perform imresize as follows:

```
%input - two images with different dimensions
I1 = imread('coins.png'); 
I2 = imread('cameraman.tif');

heightRatio = size(I1,1)/size(I2,1); %the ratio which well need to make the two images to have the same height
wantedSize = int16([size(I1,1), size(I2,2)*heightRatio]);
I2Resized = imresize(I2,wantedSize );
outIm = [I1,I2Resized];
```

if you need vertical concatination, you can use:

```
appendedIm = [I1;I2];
```

Comment: This will work only if, as I wrote in comment, when colorspaces and dimensions match.

Comment: you are correct.
a possible way to overcome the size issue, will be to change the second line as following: 
I2 = imresize(imread('coins.png'),size(I1))

Comment: @Masi if you cannot resize, how you want to deal with, possibly, different widths?

Comment: @Masi if you expand bitmap figure, you loose dpi, if you shrink you loose details. Or you can crop the image sacrificing the viewfield.

Comment: @Masi - another possibility would be padding of smaller images with zeros - depends on what is the desired output

Comment: @masi, I'll modify my answer accordingly

Comment: @Masi - I modified my answer. let me know if you have any more questions about it :)
by the way - notice that in your case you perform vertical concatanation. if you want it to be horizontal, change result=[result; imgRGB]; into result=[result, imgRGB];

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105916/discussion-between-drorco-and-masi).